# Avoid multiple calls to the same symbolic differentiation routine

Tags: symbolic

I often find myself in use cases where I have to write something like this:

```
F1[x_] := Cos[x] + Sin[x]*x;
F2[x_] := Module[
  {genericX},
  D[F1[genericX], genericX] /. {genericX -> x}
  ]
```

And then I want to run something like this:

```
Table[F2[i], {i, 1, 100}]
```

But before, I might play around with the definition `F1` until I'm sure it's the function I want to use. I assume that every iteration of the `Table` call is literally doing symbolic differentiation of `F1` and then evaluating it. Is there any way to make this more efficient? Let's say at some point I know I want to evaluate the `Table` command for several iterations and obviously I know that `F1` won't change during that execution. What's the best way to avoid the symbolic differentiation every iteration? The only option I know of would be to compute the symbolic derivative in an independent cell and then literally copy the code into a new function, but that's the kind of thing I want to avoid. Is there a more automated way to do it? Maybe function compilation is a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Use `F2[x_] = D[F1[x], x]`.  The differentiation is performed once, and `F2[x]` simply evaluates the expression produced by the differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) is for (this is mostly equivalent to @bbgodfrey's suggestion in the comments):

```
F3 = F1'
```

> Cos[#1] #1 &

Note that the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of `F1'` is `Derivative[1][F1]`. Then:

```
Trace[F3[1]]
```

> {{F3,Cos[#1] #1&},(Cos[#1] #1&)[1],Cos[1] 1,Cos[1]}

Compare this with:

```
Trace[F2[1]] //InputForm

(*
{HoldForm[F2[1]], HoldForm[Module[{genericX$}, D[F1[genericX$], genericX$] /. {genericX$ -> 1}]], 
 {{{HoldForm[F1[genericX$9510]], HoldForm[Cos[genericX$9510] + Sin[genericX$9510]*genericX$9510], 
    {HoldForm[Sin[genericX$9510]*genericX$9510], HoldForm[genericX$9510*Sin[genericX$9510]]}, 
    HoldForm[Cos[genericX$9510] + genericX$9510*Sin[genericX$9510]]}, 
   HoldForm[D[Cos[genericX$9510] + genericX$9510*Sin[genericX$9510], genericX$9510]], HoldForm[genericX$9510*Cos[genericX$9510]]}, 
  {{HoldForm[genericX$9510 -> 1], HoldForm[genericX$9510 -> 1]}, HoldForm[{genericX$9510 -> 1}]}, 
  HoldForm[genericX$9510*Cos[genericX$9510] /. {genericX$9510 -> 1}], HoldForm[1*Cos[1]], HoldForm[Cos[1]]}, HoldForm[Cos[1]]}
*)
```